# Perl - Array of objects in object

Tags: perl

I have objA which has some level of abstraction, and I'm trying to create objB that has it's own attributes but one of them is array of objA. I want to be able to create objB and populate it's array of objA with values. How this can be coded in perl?

Answer (score 2):

If your `ObjA` objects are based on hashes then you can have a field that corresponds to an array reference to store the list of `ObjB` objects.

You don't say how you want to use or access these items, but you could, say, write your methods like this

```
package ObjA;

sub new {
  my ($class);
  bless {}, $class;
}

sub add_b_object {
  my ($self, $b_obj);
  push @{ $self->{b_objects} }, $b_obj;
}
```

Then your code would look like

```
my $a_obj = ObjA->new;

for (1..3) {
  my $b_obj = ObjB->new;
  $a_obj->add_b_object($b_obj);
}
```

I hope that helps